# Combine several images algorithms

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I'm looking for algorithms that can combine images based on a quality factor. For example, you have 50-100 photographies of the same scene, but some areas had bad quality in some image because artefacts or whatever.

Now for each pixel I select the best one with a quality factor based in darkness but for sure we have a lot off possible combinations and a lot a quality measures pixel/patch/image-based.

I'm trying to research about this topic but I don't found how to describe it properly, do you know some algorithms or at least which is de name of this "problem"?

**Update**: Note some desired pixels or pixel areas only appears in a few cases, e.g. in 10 of 100 images. It causes we can't use simple averaging or similar methods.

Comment: You might try "image blending".

Comment: @sdasdadas yes, "image blending" sounds good. I will try to research some algorithms and post and answer if I found something interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is averaging the images.

If you have quality factor for each sample than u can do weighted averaging.

You use following alogorithm to improve over averaging : -

1. Divide image into block of 4*4 or 8*8
2. calculate autocorrelation in all such blocks
3. Higher autocorrelation means lesser noise hence u can give quality factor high for autocorrealation and low otherwise.
4. Do weighted averaging averaging of blocks using the quality factor defined